# PHP Session Variables Undefined Errors

Tags: php, session, timeout

I've been experiencing a very frustrating problem with a administrative website I have recently developed. I have error handling set to email myself, and randomly I receive multiple  'Error: [8] Undefined index: username' messages whilst the system is in use. I have been unable to identify the precise actions that trigger these errors however. Also, these messages aren't visible when error handling is set to echo, and the functionality of the site isn't affected.

It seems to me that the problem was caused by the session timing out, and the site not handling this correctly. However, when a login is left for a period of time then refreshed it does indeed redirect to the login page as expected with no errors.

Included at the very top of every page is:

```
session_start();
```

Next is the error handling code. This is then followed by the security code of which the first check is:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) and isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
```

if this fails, `session_destroy();` is called and it redirects to the login page.

I cannot work out why I still keep receiving

```
> Error: [8] Undefined index: username'
```

emails when an isset check is in the header of every page! The irregularity of these errors are making it impossible for me to debug.

Any insight into what might be the issue would be very much appreciated!
Many Thanks :)

Comment: What error are you getting exactly and what line is it referring to? What code is in that line?

Comment: Is there possibly a code path somewhere that would allow a `$_SESSION['username']`-using bit of code to execute without getting caught by the session checker? Could be a function or include()/require() script which bypasses the session check.

Comment: There's no code that runs autonomously without including these headers. And it's pretty much all the pages and functions which are triggering these errors, not one in particularly. All the headers and function libraries are included at the top each page using include()'s

Comment: This error is really strange; it is not PHP error. Nor ”and” is valid operator in PHP.

Comment: Okay, I've changed it to && instead. Though, this shouldn't make a difference I would have thought...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding to your debug code. Make your debug emails also send you the output of a debug_backtrace call at the time the file is output. This way you can see the exact path taken to get from the outermost script, to the line where the error is occurring.

Comment: Haven't come across debug_backtrace before, thanks! I've added it, will post more information if I can

Comment: 145 error emails later, still no further to understand the problem! debug_backtrace() is just giving the same as $errfile.

Comment: debug_backtrace() will return an array to you. The simplest solution would be to dump it's contents via print_r or var_dump. If you can provide the output as an edit to your question for us that may help.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am doing, its not helpful though the array only has one index which is the file name - and pretty much every page is throwing these errors.

Comment: Well without seeing the code, there's little more I can suggest for you. The only other thing you could do is grep your entire application for $_SESSION['username'] or 'username' or just username and take a look at those lines of code in your application. I'm still lost as to **what** is generating these errors because "> Error: [8] Undefined index: username'" is not a standard PHP error. I also notice there's a single quote on the end. Is it possible you did $_REQUEST["username'"] somewhere? I'd also point out that undefined indexes generate warnings in PHP, not errors.

Comment: So that can't be coming from PHP directly. It may be an error in something you're using to catch errors. Perhaps remove your custom error handling and turn error_reporting(E_ALL) on. That might shed some light. Lastly, did you add debug_backtrace() to your custom error handler? Or in your header code? It should go in your custom error handler, and it should be outputting a multi-dimensional array of information tracing the files/lines/functions from the error handler back to the root of the script so you can see what triggered that error exactly.

Comment: It doesn't look like a standard PHP error because the message is what my custom error handling is reporting - with default error handling no error is displayed. The trailing quote shouldn't be there (I think the person who reformatted my post to display code blocks added it there :P) The line which is generating most these errors is `You are logged in as <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>` - I added the missing semicolon on the end but this hasn't helped. I've just noticed that this error (/warning) is only generated the FIRST time each page is loaded for the session!

Comment: my error handling in php.ini is currently set to `error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED` - what should I change this to instead to hide these 'warnings' but still show important ones? Should I put `error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_WARNING` Thank you for all your help

Comment: Well for production I typically use error_reporting = E_ALL but for a live server you would want to use E_NONE unless you have a custom error handler that captures, logs, and suppresses the error output. Exposing your directory structure and system information via PHP errors is not a good idea on a live server. What I'm asking though is where are you seeing that error message. What server are you hosting on. The error message you posted here is NOT a PHP error message format. So I'm not sure what is generating the actual message. That will lead us to the code problem.

Comment: I'm using a custom error handler, `function liveErrors($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext)` which prints `echo "An error has occured ($errstr). The webmaster has been notified<br/>";` to the user, and sends more information in a email to myself. The error line i posted is generated by `$message .= "<b>Error:</b> [$errno] $errstr" . "<br/>";` - Also, even with `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_WARNING` I am still getting this index undefined error, so it can't be a warning i would think. At this stage I'd be happy with just suppressing this error message!

Comment: Try adding `$message .= '<pre>' . print_r( debug_backtrace() , true ) . '</pre>';` immediately after $message .= "<b>Error..." and post the debug email you receive here on your question for us. That may help.

Comment: debug_backtrace() is no help I've already looked at this, but its obviously something intricate I've got wrong in my system so without you looking through all my code I doubt we're gonig to solve this. But thank you greatly for your help, and I'll accept your answer anyways for you :)